# Slowing down link animation in D3 force layout

Tags: animation, d3.js, force-layout

In a force layout, I'd like to slow down the animation when two distant nodes are linked.

For example: if I have 2 nodes that are 400px apart and a link is established between them (after the inital tick has completely cooled down), I'd like to link to start at 400px and then animate down towards say 100 (or as standard link distance is set).

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Are you looking for something like the [`friction` parameter](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-friction)?

Comment: No, not specifically. When  2 nodes are linked they appear to 'snap' together (from 400px away to 100px) almost instantaneously rather than inline with the garity, friction, charge and alpha of the layout.

Comment: I almost want to animate the link from 400 to 100 slowly.

Comment: It sounds like you would have to modify the force layout implementation to achieve this.

Comment: or run the force layout to stability (without updating the vis) and then use a transition

Answer (score 2):

You can set the linkStrength to a lower value to make the linking less  abrupt. Like so:

`force.linkStrength(0.1);`

linkStrength is a value between 0 and 1.
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#linkStrength

Comment: strength is not related to animation, it's related to the strength of the position, this is incorrect